# someone explain the reasoning behind this returning a truthy

Tags: postgresql

why do this multidimensional comparison in PostgreSQL return `true`.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[[2,0], [2,1]]  && ARRAY[[3,1], [3,0]];
```

i expected the comparison to be done by value and the positions but looks like not

this is what i would expect to return `true` instead

```
SELECT ARRAY[[2,0], [3,1]]  && ARRAY[[3,1], [3,0]];
```

Comment: It all explained here [Array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because thats the way it is build....

As the manual says:

Array comparisons compare the array contents **element-by-element**, using the default B-tree comparison function for the element data type. So it looks at the smallest element and compares does.

so your just asking in the first query if the second array {{3,1}{3,0}} contains a 0, 1 or 2 (in that order). The answer is yes / true.